# Execute one make target for multiple rules

Tags: makefile

I have a list of libraries where each have 2 files (`.so`, `.dll`).
How should I create a make rule which would execute the recipe only once if both of the files are missing or if one of them is missing.

```
LIBS = alib blib
LIBS_SO = $(patsubst %, %.so, $(LIBS))
LIBS_DLL = $(patsubst %, %.dll, $(LIBS))
```

If I make this target

```
$(LIBS_SO) $(LIBS_DSS):
    cp .....
```

it copies only once for all of the the possibilities.

If I make this:

```
all : $(LIBS_SO) $(LIBS_DSS):
$(LIBS_SO) $(LIBS_DSS):
     cp .....
```

I copy in all cases of any missing files.
I want to copy the `alib` directory if both or one of the files `alib.dll` / `alib.so` is missing; the
the same with `blib`.

Comment: This is really not clear.  What is it that you are copying?  And what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us much information, but I think this will do what you want:

```
all : $(LIBS_SO) $(LIBS_DLL):
%.so %.dll:
    cp $* directory ...
```

If both `alib.so` and `alib.dll` are missing, Make will execute this rule only once.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Jonathan Leffler for catching the typo.

Answer (score 1):

You have a consistent typo of `LIBS_DSS` where you (presumably) meant `LIBS_DLL`.

Your first 'rule' is a shorthand for:

```
alib.so:
    cp ...
blib.so:
    cp ...
alib.dll:
    cp ...
blib.dll:
    cp ...
```

So, when asked to build, `make` builds the first target in the file, which is `alib.so`.  That's why it does it once.

The second version, when fixed to remove the extra colon and the typo, should work:

```
all: $(LIBS_SO) $(LIBS_DLL)

$(LIBS_SO) $(LIBS_DLL):
     cp .....
```

The default rule is `all`; to make `all`, `make` ensures that each of the files `alib.so`, `blib.so`, `alib.dll` and `blib.dll` exists and is up to date.  It should execute the commands once for each missing target.

You might conceivably run into trouble if you run a parallel `make`; `make -j4` or something similar.  It might launch four copy commands almost simultaneously to make each of the targets.  But in a non-parallel build, it will ensure `alib.so` is up to date (and if it isn't, will do the copy).  If that copy also copies `alib.dll`, then it won't recopy when it ensures `alib.dll` is up to date.